# GTK : Visual Studio Issue

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, gtk

I  had to build a debug version of GTK stack for developement reason.
After building it I set up the pkg-config for GTK and below is my
sample program in Visual Studio

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argv, char* argc)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *label;
    gtk_init(&argv, &argc);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_size_request(window, 300, 100);
    label = gtk_label_new("Click Me");
    gtk_label_set_selectable(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK(key_press_event), label);
    gtk_window_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}

static gboolean key_press_event(GtkWidget* window, GdkEvent* event, gpointer label)
{
    GtkWidget* newlabel;
    newlabel = GTK_LABEL(label);
    const gchar wtitle[100];
    strncpy(wtitle, gtk_window_get_title(GTK_WINDOW(window)), sizeof(wtitle));
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window),gtk_label_get_text(GTK_LABEL(newlabel)));
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(newlabel), wtitle);
    return false;
}
```

Below is my `pkg-config --cflags gtk-3-vs12 --msvc-syntax`  which I have included at Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options :

```
/Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/gtk /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/gdk /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/pango /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/atk /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/cairo  /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/fontconfig /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/gdk-pixbuf /Ic:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/include/glib
```

Below is my `pkg-config --libs gtk-3-vs12 --msvc-syntax`  which I have included at Project Properties -> Linker -> Command Line -> Additional Options :

```
/libpath:c:/gtk_compilation/vs12/win32/lib gtk-3-vs12.lib gdk3-win32.lib gdi32.lib imm32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib -Wl,-luuid pangocairo.lib pangowin32.lib pango-1-vs12.lib m.lib atk-1-vs12.lib cairo-gobject.lib cairo-vs10.lib gdk_pixbuf-2-vs12.lib gio-2-vs12.lib gobject-2-vs12.lib glib-2-vs12.lib intl.lib
```

Still I am getting the below errors:

```
Error   9   error C2065: 'false' : undeclared identifier    c:\users\sajith\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication8\consoleapplication8\testapp.c 28  1   ConsoleApplication8
Error   3   error C2065: 'GTK_WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL' : undeclared identifier c:\users\sajith\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication8\consoleapplication8\testapp.c 9   1   ConsoleApplication8
Error   5   error C2065: 'key_press_event' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\sajith\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication8\consoleapplication8\testapp.c 15  1   ConsoleApplication8
```

Could anybody enlighten me sorting this out?

Comment: First, the constant name is not `GTK_WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL`, it is `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL`.

Comment: Second, you need to declare `key_press_event()` before you can refer to it in `main()`. You have two options: either move the function itself to before `main()`, or add the line `static gboolean key_press_event(GtkWidget* window, GdkEvent* event, gpointer label);` to before `main()`.

Comment: Third, you want `key_press_event()` to return `FALSE`, not `false`.

Comment: Last, however, your program is illogical. It sounds like you really want a GtkEntry and to watch the `changed` event, as it seems like you want to be able to type in a window title. GtkLabel isn't good for the job.

Comment: @andlabs : lifesaver !!  Wonder how these carelessness creeped into .the program.I was a bit tired though taking a day to configure the whole gtk stack.. Thankyou so much.. :-), Sorted things out,, I agree, the program is not of much use, but just to test if things are in place..

Comment: All right then; good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the constant name is not `GTK_WINDOW_TOP_LEVEL`, it is `GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL`.

Second, you need to declare `key_press_event()` before you can refer to it in `main()`. You have two options: either move the function itself to before `main()`, or add the line

```
static gboolean key_press_event(GtkWidget* window, GdkEvent* event, gpointer label);
```

to before `main()`.

Third, you want key_press_event() to return `FALSE`, not `false`.